# displaying the user token with react-navigation

Tags: react-native, authentication, react-navigation

I'm new to react-native and want to understand how to display the user token that React-navigation normally saves after authentication.

let's use this [exemple](https://snack.expo.io/?platform=android&name=Hiding%20tab%20bar%20in%20specific%20screens%20%7C%20React%20Navigation&dependencies=%40react-native-community%2Fmasked-view%40%5E0.1.7%2C%40react-navigation%2Fnative%40%5E5.1.3%2C%40react-navigation%2Fbottom-tabs%40%5E5.2.4%2C%40react-navigation%2Fdrawer%40%5E5.3.4%2C%40react-navigation%2Fmaterial-bottom-tabs%40%5E5.1.6%2C%40react-navigation%2Fmaterial-top-tabs%40%5E5.1.6%2C%40react-navigation%2Fstack%40%5E5.2.6%2Creact-native-reanimated%40%5E1.7.0%2Creact-native-safe-area-context%40%5E0.7.3%2Creact-native-screens%40%5E2.4.0&sourceUrl=https%3A%2F%2Freactnavigation.org%2Fexamples%2F5.x%2Fauth-flow.js) on Slack to be more specific.

In this example I want to display the token (dummy-auth-token) in the HomeScreen() function. It will allow me to understand how to reuse it after authentication.

can you provide me the HomeScreen() function in your reply please ?

thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can expose `state` also into the `authContext` and access it in `HomeScreen` component:

```
const authContext = React.useMemo(() => ({
        authState: state,
        signIn: async data => {
            // In a production app, we need to send some data (usually username, password) to server and get a token
            // We will also need to handle errors if sign in failed
            // After getting token, we need to persist the token using `AsyncStorage`
            // In the example, we'll use a dummy token
            dispatch({ type: 'SIGN_IN', token: 'dummy-auth-token' });
        },
        signOut: () => dispatch({ type: 'SIGN_OUT' }),
        signUp: async data => {
            // In a production app, we need to send user data to server and get a token
            // We will also need to handle errors if sign up failed
            // After getting token, we need to persist the token using `AsyncStorage`
            // In the example, we'll use a dummy token
            dispatch({ type: 'SIGN_IN', token: 'dummy-auth-token' });
        },
    }),
    [state]
);
```

Note that we are passing `state` as dependency to `useMemo` hook.

And in your `HomeScreen`, use code like:

```
function HomeScreen() {
  const { signOut, authState } = React.useContext(AuthContext);

  return (
    <View>
      <Text>Signed in!</Text>
      <Text> Token is: {authState.userToken} </Text>
      <Button title="Sign out" onPress={signOut} />
    </View>
  );
}
```